# what does this error means : "free(): double free detected in tcache 2"

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, free, singly-linked-list

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node node_t;


void print_list(node_t *head) {
    node_t *temp = head;

    while(temp -> next != NULL) {
        printf("%d -> ", temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d ", temp->value);
    printf("\n");
}

node_t* create_new_node(int value) {
    node_t *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    temp -> value = value;

    return temp;
}

void insert_after_node(node_t *tmp, node_t *newnode) {
    newnode -> next = tmp -> next;
    tmp -> next = newnode;
}

node_t* find_node(int num, node_t* head) {
    node_t *tmp = head;
    while(tmp != NULL) {
        if(tmp -> value == num)return tmp;
        tmp = tmp -> next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

node_t* delete_head(node_t* head) {
    node_t* temp = head;
    head = head -> next;
    free(temp);

    return head;
}

void free_list(node_t* head) {
    node_t* temp = head;
    while(head != NULL) {
        free(temp);
        temp = head;
        head = head -> next;
    }
}

int main(){
    node_t *head = NULL;
    node_t *temp = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp = create_new_node(i);
        temp -> next = head;
        head = temp;
    }

    print_list(head);
    insert_after_node(
        find_node(8, head),
        create_new_node(13));
    print_list(head);

    head = delete_head(head);
    print_list(head);


    free_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 
9 -> 8 -> 13 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 
8 -> 13 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I was trying to implement basic operations of linked list using C. It has some basic functions such as creating new node using malloc, printing list, inserting node after a particular node, freeing the whole list using free. But got the error. Can anybody give me some insight of what this error might mean.

Comment: That you pass the same pointer to `free` *twice*. Now is a good time to learn how to *debug* your programs. For example I suggest you step through your `free_list` function statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values (especially keep track of where all the pointers are pointing).

Comment: Thanks got the problem in free_list. @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the function `free_list`

```
void free_list(node_t* head) {
    node_t* temp = head;
    while(head != NULL) {
        free(temp);
        temp = head;
        head = head -> next;
    }
}
```

you are deleting the memory pointed to by the pointer to the head node twice.
In the first iteration of the loop you are deleting the memory pointed to by the pointer to the head node

```
    node_t* temp = head;
    while(head != NULL) {
        free(temp);
        //...
```

and in the second iteration of the loop you are doing the same due to this assignment

```
temp = head;
```

Moreover this statement

```
head = head -> next;
```

invokes undefined behavior because there is used a pointer to the already freed memory.

The function should be defined at least the following way

```
void free_list(node_t* head) {
    while(head != NULL) {
        node_t* temp = head;
        head = head -> next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Though it would be better to define the function like

```
void free_list(node_t **head) {
    while( *head != NULL ) {
        node_t* temp = *head;
        *head = ( *head ) -> next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

And the function is called like

```
free_list( &head );
```

In this case after calling the function the pointer `head` in `main` will be equal to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void free_list(node_t* head) {
    node_t* temp = NULL;
    while(head != NULL) {
        temp = head;
        head = head -> next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Required change in the free_list(node_t* head) function. I tried to free head twice without changing it to next.